# Ruby loops to add things together

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have the following table data

```
id count
1  5
1  6
2  7
```

and I want to have an array at the end with {[1,11][2,7]}. How do I do this most efficiently?

So far I have something like:

```
IDs = Array.new
table.each do |t|
    if !IDs.include? t.id
       IDs << t.id
    end
end
```

and then i was thinking of going along the lines of `IDs.each do |i|` and have it add to a temporary variable... and then eventually returning an 2d array.

Is there a simpler way? This all comes from a mysql database so how could i run something like `SELECT id, sum(count) FROM table GROUP BY id` in a ruby on rails app?

EDIT:

Here is the migration that created the articles table

```
 class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   create_table :articles do |t|
    t.integer "nid"
    t.string "title"
    t.string "section"
    t.integer "views"
    t.date "date"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end
 end
end
```

The nid integer is the one I want to aggregate it based upon (i.e. the query would be `SELECT nid, title, section, sum(views), date FROM users WHERE user_id=?` I then need a way to pass in the model the articles belongs to (1-many) that is the user table.

My article.rb file only has `belongs_to :user` in it and user.rb has `has_many :articles`

EDIT 2:

I made a named scope in my article.rb file called :sum with lambda {find_by_sql("Select .... ")}

the question is now how do I put the wildcard in there for the `WHERE user_id = ?` so that I only grab the articles for the right user? right now my `user_controller` has the `@articles = Articles.sum` parameter in it.

Comment: Yes you could...its simplier if you run the query proposed by yourself

Comment: where do I do that? Named scope in the model.rb file?

Comment: Is this table associated with some model? What is your models structure?

Comment: Yes, post the relevant code where the table object is created

Comment: I posted the model, through a controller I currently get a articles variable but when I do articles.each it simply outputs all them without adding the same NID's views together

Comment: You might want to redesign your models - what is the difference between articles with some nid - what they represents? It looks like they represent same abstract object with different attributes - it would be probably a good idea to convert those into some has_many association. If you want to redesign your models, please post your model's structure to CodeReview: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: nid is short for Node ID which is unique identifier for each article. each article has a certain amount of views (and were posted by a user therefore user has many articles) the views are tracked daily which means that the same nid can occur twice with different dates. I want to add them together and output the total views of that article

Comment: As I thought, You have one article, which has_many daily_views. Split your model into two models, one is article, second one is daily_views (with id, article_id and views_count). Then you will be able to do: `article.daily_views.sum(:views_count)` which will result with a correct clean sql query.

Comment: oh my god! DUH! wow that was a brain-fart on my side. Thank you so much!

Comment: if you put it as an answer I'll accept and upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always execute any sql query using:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT id, sum(count) FROM table GROUP BY id').values
```

However this is not ideal, as it is not db agnostic. Usually queries like that are being handled very well by models, however query structure depends on how your models are defined, so no more help until you share those with us.

UPDATE:

After some discussion it seems like the best way to go is redesigning your models.
Instead of having multiple duplicates of an article with different view_counts, create DailyViews model conaining id, article_id and views_count. Associate it with Article model via has_many association. Then you can simply call:

```
article.daily_views.sum(:views_count)
```

to count all the views on given article. I would probably wrap the above into another method `total_views`. You would also be able to define scopes on a new model, so it will make your live much easier to calculate view count for given month or year.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = Article.select('nid, sum(views) as count').group('nid')

 a.inject({})do |res, i |
  res[i.status] = i.total
   res
  end
```

it will give you result like { '1' => '11', '2' => '7'}

Comment: where would I put that? into the model?

Comment: not necessary, you can put it in concern, model anywhere you want to  compute.